Unable to get libmpdec-dev from remote repository on Ubuntu 24.04using apt-get
I was unable to install libmpdec-dev, needed to build Python from source, on Ubuntu 24.04. This package was previously available on 22.04 and earlier. It looks as if most of the packages needed to build Python from source have had their names changed for 24.04, but in all cases except libmpdec, apt was able to supply a package with the new name. Any suggestions on what should be done?

See https://tracker.debian.org/news/1518602/removed-251-2-from-unstable/. Our Debian upstream says the package should no longer be needed to build from source. Hence the removal. If incorrect, please let Debian know.

You should mark this one as resolved.

It turns out that libmpdec-dev is obsolete and not needed anymore. I was able to build Python sucessfully.
